# memory allocation in structures in c

Tags: c, pointers

I wrote the following code just to verify what was written in one of the books I use to study c. the memory allocated to the first variable i.e character variable does not make sense. the memory allocated is 4 bytes instead of 1.can someone help me where did i go wrong?

```
    struct book
    {
        char name;
        int price;
        int pages;
    };
    struct book b1={'a',23,45},b2={'d',56,34},b3={'e',38,79};
    printf("%p\t %p\t %p\n",&b1,&b2,&b3);
    printf("%p\t %p\t %p\n",&b1.name,&b1.price,&b1.pages);
```

```
0x7ffd4f9a0384     0x7ffd4f9a0390     0x7ffd4f9a039c
0x7ffd4f9a0384     0x7ffd4f9a0388     0x7ffd4f9a038c
```

Comment: Where are you getting the idea that four bytes are being allocated for `name`? Your output just shows the addresses of your structs.

Comment: i edited it, can you please check it now.

Comment: Padding may be inserted automatically to ensure later members are naturally aligned. Compare with `struct b{char a; char b;};` and `offsetof(struct b, b}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're confusing addresses with size. The `printf` statements should be be written like this:

```c
printf("%zu\t %zu\t %zu\n", sizeof(b1), sizeof(b2), sizeof(b3));
printf("%zu\t %zu\t %zu\n", sizeof(b1.name), sizeof(b1.price), sizeof(b1.pages));
```

This gives you the following output:

```
12       12      12
1        4       4
```

As for why the structs are 12 bytes in size while only holding 9 bytes of data, that has to do with struct alignment.

Comment: thanks!!! your answer explains my doubt